# Print nth line after line

Tags: python, iterable

I am trying to print the nth line after a specific line in a file:

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

velerror = []
divergence = []
mesh = []
timestep = []
totaltime = []

for files in glob.glob('*.out'):
    f = open(files, 'r')
    for line in f:
        if "Maximum Velocity Error:" in line:
            velerror.append(float(line[32:40]))
        if "Grid Dimensions, Mesh" in line:
            mesh.append(int(line[27]))
        if "Time Step  " in line:
            timestep.append(int(line[17:27].strip()))
        if "Total time:" in line:
            totaltime.append(float(line[47:57].strip()))
            #Print nth line after line


totaltime = totaltime[0::9]

print(velerror)
print(mesh)
print(timestep)
print(totaltime)
```

Is there a function like next() that goes to the next nth line?

Comment: So you need to print each nth line is it so? in the last if? Regardless of any other condition?

Comment: Print each nth line after line which contains the string ""Total time:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(see the edit for a version without `readlines`, [live demo](https://repl.it/JtrS/0))

> print the nth line after a specific line in a file

It the file fits into memory use `readlines` and slicing:

```
def print_after(source, specific_line_number, skip_lines):
    for line in source[specific_line_number::skip_lines]:
        print(line)

lines = [f'line {i:2}' for i in range(30)] # readlines here
print_after(lines, 7, 2)
```

In your code:

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

velerror = []
divergence = []
mesh = []
timestep = []
totaltime = []

for files in glob.glob('*.out'):
    f = open(files, 'r')
    for line in f:
        if "Maximum Velocity Error:" in line:
            velerror.append(float(line[32:40]))
        if "Grid Dimensions, Mesh" in line:
            mesh.append(int(line[27]))
        if "Time Step  " in line:
            timestep.append(int(line[17:27].strip()))
        if "Total time:" in line:
            totaltime.append(float(line[47:57].strip()))
            for line in islice
            break  # Stop consuming lines (?)


totaltime = totaltime[0::9]

print(velerror)
print(mesh)
print(timestep)
print(totaltime)
```

EDIT: Using islice as rassahah suggested can help you save some memory:

```
from itertools import islice

import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

velerror = []
divergence = []
mesh = []
timestep = []
totaltime = []

for files in glob.glob('*.out'):
    f = open(files, 'r')
    for line in f:
        if "Maximum Velocity Error:" in line:
            velerror.append(float(line[32:40]))
        if "Grid Dimensions, Mesh" in line:
            mesh.append(int(line[27]))
        if "Time Step  " in line:
            timestep.append(int(line[17:27].strip()))
        if "Total time:" in line:
            totaltime.append(float(line[47:57].strip()))
            break
    skip_lines = 2
    offset = skip_lines-1
    for line in islice(f, offset, None, skip_lines):
        print(line)


totaltime = totaltime[0::9]

print(velerror)
print(mesh)
print(timestep)
print(totaltime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `readlines()`

```
i = 0;
lines = f.readlines()
while 1:
    line = lines[i]
    if not line:
        break
    if "Maximum Velocity Error:" in line:
            velerror.append(float(line[32:40]))
    if "Grid Dimensions, Mesh" in line:
            mesh.append(int(line[27]))
    if "Time Step  " in line:
            timestep.append(int(line[17:27].strip()))
    if "Total time:" in line:
            totaltime.append(float(line[47:57].strip()))
            i = i + 8
    i++
```

Answer (score 0):

To print nth line from each file

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

velerror = []
divergence = []
mesh = []
timestep = []
totaltime = []
n_check = 5    # let n be 5

for files in glob.glob('*.out'):
    f = open(files, 'r')
    for i,line in enumerate(f):
        if "Maximum Velocity Error:" in line:
            velerror.append(float(line[32:40]))
        if "Grid Dimensions, Mesh" in line:
            mesh.append(int(line[27]))
        if "Time Step  " in line:
            timestep.append(int(line[17:27].strip()))
        if "Total time:" in line:
            totaltime.append(float(line[47:57].strip()))
        if not i%n_check:
            print(line)
```

Comment: please, use `enumerate` for counting lines. `for i,line in enumerate(f)`

Answer (score 0):

you can search that specific line using keyword and print nth line of second keyword .The code is given below

```
search=open("test.txt",'r') 
for line in search:
   if "first_keyword" in line:
      while not "second_keywoed" in line:
          line=next(search)
      if "second_keyword" in line:
          print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the linecache module for this

```
import linecache

line_count = 0
n_lines = 4  # just an example

for file in glob.glob('*.out'):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line_count += 1
            if "Maximum Velocity Error:" in line:
                velerror.append(float(line[32:40]))
            if "Grid Dimensions, Mesh" in line:
                mesh.append(int(line[27]))
            if "Time Step  " in line:
                timestep.append(int(line[17:27].strip()))
            if "Total time:" in line:
                totaltime.append(float(line[47:57].strip()))
                interesting_line = linecache.getline(file, line_count + n_lines)
                print(interesting_line)
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 1968: invalid continuation byte

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a function like next() that goes to the next nth line?

There is a function **next()** that delivers the current line and goes to the next. In the package **itertools** there is a function **islice()**, that builds a subrange of an iterable (i.e. a thing for which **next()** works on). Luckily, a filehandle (that **f** that you get from your **open()** call) also is an iterable, so you can combine these three pieces:

```
from itertools import islice
...
if "Total time:" in line:
  totaltime.append(float(line[47:57].strip()))
  #Print nth line after line
  # Skips to the 5th line, and stops and the 6th line;
  # counting begins at 0, so by human standards this
  # actually prints the 6th line:
  next_5th_line = next (islice (f, 5, 6))
  print (next_5th_line)
```

After executing that, the loop will continue after the line that was printed out, so some lines will be simply discarded.